# Does Rails Precompiled Images Names Affect SEO?

Tags: seo, images, ruby-on-rails, google-image-search

I manage a Rails 4 app deployed to Heroku. Because of our setup, we always need to precompile our images before deploying to Heroku. The effect of this is that our images in production end up with names like:

http://website.com/assets/real-descriptive-image-name-a2e4d6d98e04f2f995caf02a0fdbdd2f0f88f3db8fcad1749db25c705825a527.png

The long string at the end is generated by rails and only happens in production. Does it negatively impact my SEO? Are there way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: No. It causes no harm. It adds no value. But it causes no harm as long as you are incorporating some semantic value into the name. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it negatively impact my SEO?

No, not at all.

> Are there way to prevent this from happening?

You can use image related text surrounded it, for example [figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) tag will help you here. Alt text will also help you here. Google just want to know that, this image is related to this. And there are many of way to tell it.

Google can even use your paragraphs note to know about the images, I have notice some of quora answer with pics are indexed very well in image search, without using proper image name, alt, title, and figcaption tag.